# How to convert between TFM (Target framework moniker) and FrameworkName?

Tags: c#, target-framework

E.g.

**`netstandard2.0`** (from [Supported target frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#supported-target-frameworks)) which is used as `<TargetFramework>` in `*.csproj` files or as folder name in NuGet packages internal structure,

and

**`.NETStandard,Version=v2.0`** which is accepted by `System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.versioning.frameworkname)'s constructor or can be a value of `TargetFrameworkAttribute.FrameworkName`.

How to convert those *strings* from one form to another? At least one (any) direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the source code of [NuGet.Frameworks](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/tree/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Frameworks):

Here is the method that converts TFM to FrameworkName:
https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Frameworks/NuGetFrameworkFactory.cs#L575

(e.g. `netstandard2.0` to `.NETStandard,Version=v2.0`)

**UPDATE #1**

The good news is that it is available as a NuGet package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Frameworks/

Here is a .NET 6 Console Application:

```cs
using NuGet.Frameworks;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;

var tfmNetstandard20 = NuGetFramework.ParseFolder("netstandard20");

var fwNetstandard20 = new FrameworkName(tfmNetstandard20.DotNetFrameworkName);

Console.WriteLine(tfmNetstandard20);
Console.WriteLine(fwNetstandard20);
```

The output will be:

```sh
.NETStandard,Version=v2.0
.NETStandard,Version=v2.0
```

Comment: Thanks. But the idea is not to write (or copy) and maintain any private conversion code (either translation table, or to play with regexs), but to use some [one-liner?] Microsoft's solution. If there is one.

Comment: @Ilyan, fortunately it is available as a nuget package. See my updated answer.

Comment: I expected for something in System namespace, something built-in. But NuGet is almost as good.